# Printer not browseable by SAMBA

Tags: 12.10, samba

I have added a samba printer. But it is not browseable, Please find the following samba configuration,

```
###############Global Definitions############
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = Samba File Server
security = user
valid users = @smbgrp
deadtime = 10
time server = Yes
log level = 3
log file = /var/log/samba/%m. log
max log size = 50
socket options = SO_KEEPALIVE IPTOS_LOWDELAY TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_SNDBUF=8192
os level = 255
domain master = No
dns proxy = No
kernel oplocks = No
printcap name = /run/cups/printcap  
printing = cups 
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
hosts allow = XX.XX.XX., XX.XX.XX.
hosts deny = All
cups options = raw
veto files = /.recycle/, /thumbs.db/
guest account = nobody

###############Share Definitions##################
[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers
    browseable = Yes
read only = Yes
guest ok = No

[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    path = /var/spool/samba
    browseable = yes
    printable = yes
    read only = no
##########################################################
```

But `testparm -s` result is showing `browseable = no`. Am using `ubuntu 12.10` how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

12.10 uses CUPS!!

Try this on your browser `http://127.0.0.1:631/printers/`, there you will see your printer **queue name** to use on window$ *network shared printer* (a string without spaces, and remove any tcp/ip ports *on window$* that have the same name that you may have misscreated or it will conflict/misbehave).

Try this while setting up a new shared printer on windows `http://YourHostIP:631/printers/TheQueueName`. I dont have another linux on my home so I dont have info for *linux to linux*.

Also make it sure the port 631 is allowed on your firewall on linux.

If you need more tips, say so.